# Add video hero/header to wordpress main site (storefront)

Tags: video-header

I want to have a video header on my main WordPress site. I use `Page specific stylesheet`, on my main page, with this code, to make the header on the whole page:

```
.site-header {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I do also use `Video Background`, to insert a video. This is how it looks:

[image]

It works on desktop, but on smaller screens, it shows grey, on the top and the bottom. On phones, it doesn't show up at all. Can I fix, or would you recommend another methode?

Link to the page: www.gullhaugensport.no/hannepanne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the CSS on your video element. Remove the `max-width: 100%` and set the height to `height: 100vh;`. It will crop the edges of the video on smaller screens, but that can't be helped if you want it to be full screen height.

Comment: I changed the max-width to none. It works on desktop browser, but it is not showing up on mobile. How can I fix this?

Comment: It works fine on my Android phone. If you are looking at it on an iOS device you should know that autoplay is a problem. Have a look at this article: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/